# How can I pass values to the URL in ASP.NET Core 6 MVC?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, url-routing

I am trying to pass an `Id` from one controller to another by passing the value in the url and calling it in the other controller. So far I have tried everything and I can't get it to work. Can anyone help?

Here is the flight controller

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult SearchFlights(string origin, string destination, DateTime departureDate)
{
    var flights = _context.Flights
                          .Where(f => f.DepartureAirport == origin 
                                      && f.ArrivalAirport == destination 
                                      && f.DepartureDatetime.Date == departureDate.Date)
                          .ToList();

    ViewBag.Origin = origin;
    ViewBag.Destination = destination;
    ViewBag.DepartureDate = departureDate;

    return View(flights);
}

[HttpPost]
public IActionResult SearchFlights(int flightId)
{
    string url = string.Format("/Reservation/AddPassenger?flightId={0}", flightId);
    return Redirect(url);
}
```

Here is the `ReservationController`:

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult AddPassenger([FromRoute] int flightId)
{
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public IActionResult AddPassenger(Passenger passanger, [FromRoute] int flightId)
{
    Passenger passenger = new Passenger()
        {
            Name = passanger.Name,
            Email = passanger.Email,
            PhoneNumber = passanger.PhoneNumber,
            PassportNumber = passanger.PassportNumber,
            PaymentMethod = passanger.PaymentMethod,

        };

    _context.Passengers.Add(passenger);
    _context.SaveChanges();

    int passengerId = passenger.PassengerId;

    Reservation reservation = new Reservation()
        {
            FlightId = flightId,
            SeatId = 2,
            PassengerId = passengerId,
            ReservationStatus= "Confirmed",
            ReservationDate= DateTime.Now,
        };

    _context.Reservations.Add(reservation); 
    _context.SaveChanges(); 

    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Essentially this is a search mechanism to display the data when the user clicks book the ID should be sent to the Url, but it doesn't, the url in the browser is like this

```
https://localhost:2213/Reservation/AddPassenger?.
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: "when the user clicks book the ID should be sent to the Url, but it dosen't, the url in the browser is like this" What do you mean? You cannot get the  flightId in your SearchFlights post? How you post it?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass value from one controller to another controller in .netcore, I have a suggestion like below:
Try to use [TempData](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controller.tempdata?view=aspnetcore-7.0):

In flight controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult SearchFlights(int flightId)
{
       TempData["flightId"] = flightId;
      return RedirectToAction("AddPassenger", "Reservation");
}
```

And in Reservation Controller:

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult AddPassenger()
{ 
    var flightId = TempData["flightId"];
    return View();
}
```

result:

[image]

**Or**

Just Remove the `[FromRoute]`

```
 [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult AddPassenger( int flightId)
        {
            return View();
        }
```

result:

[image]